# Is there a way to plot a single level curve of a function of x and y through a given point?

Tags: plotting

For example, I am trying to plot the single level curve of

```
f(x,y)=xsin[y/x]+ysin[2x]
```

that goes through the point (3pi,3pi). Can anyone show me how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for illustrative purposes:

```
f[x_, y_] := x Sin[y/x] + y Sin[2 x]
pt = f[3 Pi, 3 Pi];
plot = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}, {y, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}, 
   MeshFunctions -> (#3 &), Mesh -> {{pt}}, MeshStyle -> {Thick, Red},
    PlotPoints -> 100, ColorFunctionScaling -> False];
Show[plot, 
 Graphics3D[{Yellow, PointSize[0.03], Point[{{3 Pi, 3 Pi, pt}}]}]]
```

visualizes the level curve (and point in yellow):
[image]

Contour plot can visualize the level curve:

```
    ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}, {y, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}, 
 Contours -> {pt}, ContourShading -> None, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{3 Pi, 3 Pi}]}]
```

[image]

You can improve quality with plot points.

Answer (score 1):

Define the function you want to plot `f[x,y]` and the value(s) you want to plot and then use the `ContourPlot` command. You get somewhat different pictures by choosing different regions of x,y to plot over.

```
f[x_, y_] := x Sin[y/x] + y Sin[2 x]; 
ContourPlot[f[x, y] == f[3 Pi, 3 Pi], {x, 0, 25}, {y, 0, 25}]
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks bill s!

Comment: @ ubpdqn very sexy!